# Standard notation for order of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

How do you denote the order of a square matrix, assuming it wasn't provided beforehand? For example, if I wanted to state something like,

$$order(A) = n \rightarrow |A| > 2^n$$

what would be the correct replacement for "$order(A)$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some authors, especially those in applied linear algebra, use [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) notation for notational conventions. For instance, I have seen use authors use $1:n$ instead of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Thus, in your situation, it might be good to use $\text{size}(A)=n$ to indicate that $A$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix (from the MATLAB function '[size](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html)').